# How integrate a websocket between tornado and uwsgi?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, uwsgi

I'm work in a little message chat project and i use tornado websocket for the communication between web browser and the server here all work fine but i was working with tornado integrate web framework and i want to configurate my app for run on web server nginx -uwsgi , i read for integrate tornado and uwsgi i have to run the application tornado in wsgi mode but on this way the asynchronous methods are not supported. And i ask what is the best way for integrate a tornado websocket to uwsgi? Or i should run tornado websocket and configure it on nginx separate of the rest my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uWSGI tornado loop engine is no more than a proof of concept, you could try to use it but native uWSGI websockets support or having nginx routing requests to both uWSGI and tornado are better (and more solid) choices for sure.